# Tkinter Game ValueError

Tags: python, tkinter, game-development, tkinter-canvas

I have a problem with my Python 3 program.
The code is running but there is a `ValueError` in some part of the code:

```
from itertools import cycle
from random import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import messagebox
import time as t
import pygame as p


eggs = []
hearts = []


def sound():
    p.mixer.init()
    eg = p.mixer.Sound('ec.mp3')
    eg.play()
    t.sleep(5)

def create_egg():
    x = randrange(10, 750)
    y = 40
    new_egg = c.create_oval(x, y, x + egg_width, y + egg_height, fill=next(color_cycle), width=0)
    eggs.append(new_egg)
    root.after(egg_interval,create_egg)

def move_eggs():
    for egg in eggs:
        (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
        c.move(egg, 0, 10)
        if egg_y2 > canvas_height:
            egg_dropped(egg)
    root.after(egg_speed, move_eggs)

def egg_dropped(egg):
    eggs.remove(egg)
    c.delete(egg)
    lose_a_life()
    if lives_remaining == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo('Game Over', 'Final Score: ' + str(score))

        root.destroy()

def lose_a_life():
    global lives_remaining
    lives_remaining -= 1
    c.itemconfigure(lives_text, text='Lives: '+ str(heart * lives_remaining))

def check_catch():
    (catcher_x, catcher_y, catcher_x2,catcher_y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    for egg in eggs:
        (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2,egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
        if catcher_x < egg_x and egg_x2 < catcher_x2 and catcher_y2 - egg_y2 < 40:
            eggs.remove(egg)
            c.delete(egg)
            increase_score(egg_score)

    root.after(100, check_catch)

def increase_score(points):
    global score, egg_speed, egg_interval
    score += points
    egg_speed = int(egg_speed * dificulty_factor)
    egg_interval = int(egg_interval * dificulty_factor)

    c.itemconfigure(score_text, text='Score: '+ str(score))

def create_heart():
    x = randrange(10, 750)
    y = 40
    new_heart = life_heart
    hearts.append(new_heart)
    root.after(egg_interval - 100,create_heart)

def check_catch_life():
    (catcher_x, catcher_y, catcher_x2,catcher_y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    for life_heart in heart:
        (life_heart_x, life_heart_y, life_heart_x2, life_heart_y2) = c.coords(life_heart)
        if catcher_x < life_heart_x and life_heart_x2 < catcher_x2 and catcher_y2 - life_heart_y2 < 40:
            hearts.remove(life_heart)
            c.delete(life_heart)
            increase_life()

    root.after(100, check_catch_life)

def increase_life():
    global lives_remaining
    lives_remaining += 2
    c.itemconfigure(lives_text, text='Lives: '+ str(heart * lives_remaining))

def move_heart():
    for life_heart in hearts:
        (life_heart_x, life_heart_y, life_heart_x2, life_heart_y2) = c.coords(life_heart)
        c.move(life_heart, 0, 10)
        if life_heart_y2 > canvas_height:
            life_dropped(life_heart)
    root.after(egg_speed + randrange(10, 1000), move_heart)

def life_dropped(life):
    hearts.remove(life)
    c.delete(life)


def move_left(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x1 > 0:
        c.move(catcher,-20, 0)

def move_right(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x2 < canvas_width:
        c.move(catcher, 20, 0)

gaming = True

canvas_width = 1000
canvas_height = 400

root = Tk()
root.title('Egg Catcher')

c = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width,height=canvas_height, background='deep sky blue')

c.create_rectangle(-5, canvas_height - 100, canvas_width + 5, canvas_height +5, fill='sea green', width=0)
c.create_oval(-80,-80,120,120,fill='orange', width=0)

c.pack()

color_cycle = cycle(['light blue','light yellow', 'light pink','light cyan'])
life_heart = u'\u2764'

egg_width = 45
egg_height = 55
egg_score = 10
egg_speed = 500
egg_interval = 4000
dificulty_factor = 0.95

catcher_color = 'red'
catcher_width = 100
catcher_height = 100

catcher_start_x = canvas_width / 2 - catcher_width / 2
catcher_start_y = canvas_height - catcher_height - 2
catcher_start_x2 = catcher_start_x + catcher_width
catcher_start_y2 = catcher_start_y + catcher_height

catcher = c.create_arc(catcher_start_x, catcher_start_y, catcher_start_x2, catcher_start_y2, start=200, extent = 140, style='arc', outline = catcher_color, width=10)

game_font = font.nametofont('TkFixedFont')
game_font.config(size=18)

score = 0
score_text = c.create_text(10,10,anchor='nw',font=game_font,fill='darkblue',text='Score: ' + str(score))

lives_remaining = 3
heart = u'\u2764'

lives_text = c.create_text(canvas_width-100,10,anchor='ne',font=game_font,fill='darkblue',text='Lives ' + str(heart * lives_remaining))

c.bind('<Left>', move_left)
c.bind('<Right>', move_right)
c.focus_set()

root.after(2,sound)
root.after(1000, create_egg)
root.after(1000, move_eggs)
root.after(1000, check_catch)

root.after(1000, create_heart)
root.after(1000, move_heart)
root.after(1000, check_catch_life)

root.mainloop()
```

And Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lukgu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\lukgu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 839, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\lukgu\OneDrive\programing\python scripts\python games\Egg_Catcher.py", line 88, in check_catch_life
    (life_heart_x, life_heart_y, life_heart_x2, life_heart_y2) = c.coords(life_heart)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)
```

I tried lot of things, the egg cords was received, but not life heart coords.
I want to create life hearts and take it coordinates.
I don't know how to fix this `ValueError`.

Comment: Look at how you create eggs vs how you create hearts, seems like you're making a list of heart **strings** vs a list of egg **c.create_ovals**

Comment: What @HWW said. You need to create a tkinter canvas object to display the heart symbol rather than just adding the heart string to a list. Try using the `create_text` widget to create a new canvas item that contains the heart symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code partially solves your problem.

It will create a new text widget on the canvas that displays the heart symbol on the screen and it will move the heart down the screen periodically.

Hopefully you can use this example to progress your game further and fully implement the catching of the hearts.

```
from itertools import cycle
from random import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import messagebox
import time as t
#import pygame as p


eggs = []
hearts = []


def sound():
    #p.mixer.init()
    #eg = p.mixer.Sound('ec.mp3')
    #eg.play()
    #t.sleep(5)
    print("sound")

def create_egg():
    x = randrange(10, 750)
    y = 40
    new_egg = c.create_oval(x, y, x + egg_width, y + egg_height, fill=next(color_cycle), width=0)
    eggs.append(new_egg)
    root.after(egg_interval,create_egg)

def move_eggs():
    for egg in eggs:
        (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
        c.move(egg, 0, 10)
        if egg_y2 > canvas_height:
            egg_dropped(egg)
    root.after(egg_speed, move_eggs)

def egg_dropped(egg):
    eggs.remove(egg)
    c.delete(egg)
    lose_a_life()
    if lives_remaining == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo('Game Over', 'Final Score: ' + str(score))

        root.destroy()

def lose_a_life():
    global lives_remaining
    lives_remaining -= 1
    c.itemconfigure(lives_text, text='Lives: '+ str(heart * lives_remaining))

def check_catch():
    (catcher_x, catcher_y, catcher_x2,catcher_y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    for egg in eggs:
        (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2,egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
        if catcher_x < egg_x and egg_x2 < catcher_x2 and catcher_y2 - egg_y2 < 40:
            eggs.remove(egg)
            c.delete(egg)
            increase_score(egg_score)

    root.after(100, check_catch)

def increase_score(points):
    global score, egg_speed, egg_interval
    score += points
    egg_speed = int(egg_speed * dificulty_factor)
    egg_interval = int(egg_interval * dificulty_factor)

    c.itemconfigure(score_text, text='Score: '+ str(score))

def create_heart():
    global hearts
    x = randrange(10, 750)
    y = 40
    new_heart = c.create_text(x,y,anchor='ne',font=game_font,fill='darkblue',text=str(heart))
    hearts.append(new_heart)
    root.after(egg_interval - 100,create_heart)

def check_catch_life():
    (catcher_x, catcher_y, catcher_x2,catcher_y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    for life_heart in hearts:
        print(c.coords(life_heart))
        (life_heart_x, life_heart_y) = c.coords(life_heart)
        if catcher_x < life_heart_x and life_heart_x < catcher_x2 and catcher_y2 - life_heart_y < 40:
            hearts.remove(life_heart)
            c.delete(life_heart)
            increase_life()

    root.after(100, check_catch_life)

def increase_life():
    global lives_remaining
    lives_remaining += 2
    c.itemconfigure(lives_text, text='Lives: '+ str(heart * lives_remaining))

def move_heart():
    print('moving hearts')
    for life_heart in hearts:
        (life_heart_x, life_heart_y) = c.coords(life_heart)
        c.move(life_heart, 0, 10)
        if life_heart_y > canvas_height:
            life_dropped(life_heart)
    root.after(egg_speed + randrange(10, 1000), move_heart)

def life_dropped(life):
    hearts.remove(life)
    c.delete(life)


def move_left(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x1 > 0:
        c.move(catcher,-20, 0)

def move_right(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x2 < canvas_width:
        c.move(catcher, 20, 0)

gaming = True

canvas_width = 1000
canvas_height = 400

root = Tk()
root.title('Egg Catcher')

c = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width,height=canvas_height, background='deep sky blue')

c.create_rectangle(-5, canvas_height - 100, canvas_width + 5, canvas_height +5, fill='sea green', width=0)
c.create_oval(-80,-80,120,120,fill='orange', width=0)

c.pack()

color_cycle = cycle(['light blue','light yellow', 'light pink','light cyan'])
life_heart = u'\u2764'

egg_width = 45
egg_height = 55
egg_score = 10
egg_speed = 500
egg_interval = 4000
dificulty_factor = 0.95

catcher_color = 'red'
catcher_width = 100
catcher_height = 100

catcher_start_x = canvas_width / 2 - catcher_width / 2
catcher_start_y = canvas_height - catcher_height - 2
catcher_start_x2 = catcher_start_x + catcher_width
catcher_start_y2 = catcher_start_y + catcher_height

catcher = c.create_arc(catcher_start_x, catcher_start_y, catcher_start_x2, catcher_start_y2, start=200, extent = 140, style='arc', outline = catcher_color, width=10)

game_font = font.nametofont('TkFixedFont')
game_font.config(size=18)

score = 0
score_text = c.create_text(10,10,anchor='nw',font=game_font,fill='darkblue',text='Score: ' + str(score))

lives_remaining = 3
heart = u'\u2764'

lives_text = c.create_text(canvas_width-100,10,anchor='ne',font=game_font,fill='darkblue',text='Lives ' + str(heart * lives_remaining))

c.bind('<Left>', move_left)
c.bind('<Right>', move_right)
c.focus_set()

root.after(2,sound)
root.after(1000, create_egg)
root.after(1000, move_eggs)
root.after(1000, check_catch)

root.after(1000, create_heart)
root.after(1000, move_heart)
root.after(1000, check_catch_life)

root.mainloop()
```

(Note: I have removed the sound since I don't have pygame installed, just comment it back in)